# Calculate values for col E,F&G and then resets and starts over

Tags: sql

I need to do the following using SQL 2008 :-

Sample Data all from the same table:-

```
GroupBy   Pot        OrderBy    Cost     Start       CostAlloc   End        
   A         B      C     D       E         F          G    
24323   641883.31   0   400000  641883.31   0       641883.31       
24323   641883.31   1   50000   641883.31   50000   591883.31       
24323   641883.31   2   50000   591883.31   50000   541883.31       
24323   641883.31   3   50000   541883.31   50000   491883.31       
24323   641883.31   4   50000   491883.31   50000   441883.31       
24328   644859.33   0   400000  644859.33   0       644859.33       
24328   644859.33   1   50000   644859.33   50000   594859.33       
24328   644859.33   2   50000   594859.33   50000   544859.33       
24328   644859.33   3   50000   544859.33   50000   494859.33       
24328   644859.33   4   50000   494859.33   50000   444859.33       
24328   644859.33   5   8000    444859.33   8000    436859.33       
24328   644859.33   6   8000    436859.33   8000    428859.33
```

We have a pot (B) for each GroupBy Value (A)
This pot needs to be allocated to each row using cost(D) excluding where OrderBy(C) =0
The allocation will reset each time the groupby changes.
the values are stored in E,F,G
F= cost; E=Bal bfwd, G= E-F

Comment: very much unclear? I read two times but no clue what exactly you want to do

Comment: You requirement is very unclear.  Perhaps a sample output would help illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: what specific rdbms is this?

Comment: A B C D E F G
24323 150000 0 400000 150000 0 150000
24323  1 50000 150000 50000 100000
24323  2 50000 100000 50000 50000
24323  3 50000 50000 50000 0
24328 600000 0 400000 600000 0 600000
24328  1 50000 600000 50000 550000
24328  2 50000 550000 50000 500000
24328  3 50000 500000 50000 450000

Comment: A=list of assets (iw ould need to Group By these)      
B=Money Spent to date in total for each A      
C=Rank=Sequence of allocating the money spent(B)Order by these      
D=maximum amount that can be allocated to the each row      
E=if Rank=0 then this must be the total money spent, otherwise      
this must be the balance left over from previous row(G).      
F= D where Rank(C) is not 0 and where      
the balance(G) is less than D then allocate the balance remaining.      
G=E-F

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what rdbms you are using but if it is SQL Server 2012 or 2014 you can do this

You are basically trying to keep a running total but exclude the rows where c = 0 from the calculation. I used a case statement to handle that. And then use `ROWS BETWEEN` to tell it which rows within the window to calculate.

**[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d73b7/3)**

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    ISNULL(b - SUM(CASE WHEN c = 0 THEN 0 ELSE d END) OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY c ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), b) AS e,
    CASE WHEN c = 0 THEN 0 ELSE d END AS f,
    ISNULL(b - SUM(CASE WHEN c = 0 THEN 0 ELSE d END) OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY c ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), b) AS g
FROM
    yourTable
```

Comment: Hi JChao,Thanks for the feedback. i am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I will give this a try an dlet you know the outcome.

Comment: Hi JChao, i have loaded the code as follows:-   SELECT
    ANLN1,
    Cost,
    Ranking,
    ReplacementValue,
    ISNULL(Cost - SUM(CASE WHEN Ranking = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ReplacementValue END) 
    OVER(PARTITION BY ANLN1 ORDER BY Ranking ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), Cost) 
AS [opening balance]CASE WHEN Ranking = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ReplacementValue END AS [Value Allocated], ISNULL(Cost - SUM(CASE WHEN Ranking = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ReplacementValue END) OVER(PARTITION BY ANLN1 ORDER BY Ranking ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW), Cost) AS [closing balance] FROM TestCopex

Comment: but i get the following error:-                                                                       Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.

Comment: This won't work in 2008R2. `OVER` was expanded in 2012.

Comment: Hi JChao, any ideas then for 2008R2?